# How to find the name of a Nix package to install it in configuration.nix?

Tags: nixos, nix

Suppose I search for a package to install using [`nix-env`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-env)'s [`--query`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#idm46912466717184) operation:

```
$ nix-env -qa 'aspell.*en'
aspell-dict-en-7.1-0
```

I write this package name in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, NixOS's main [configuration file](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#ch-configuration):

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  aspell-dict-en
];
```

Yet if I run `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`, NixOS command to [update the configuration](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-changing-config) and install all system-wide packages specified by [declaratively](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-declarative-package-mgmt), it aborts with an error:

```
error: undefined variable ‘aspell-dict-en’ at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:44:5
```

I know that for many packages, although not all, the name that `nix-env` returns and the name one should specify in `environment.systemPackages` configuration option are different, but I don't understand the logic. How do I install a package that I found through `nix-env`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

NixOS community has three manuals, always consult them first, if you're stuck:

- [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/), for the package manager
- [NixOS manual](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/), for the operating system
- [Nixpkgs manual](http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/), for Nix package infrastructure

Every package on Nix is specified by a Nix expression. A Nix expression is some text, written in Nix language, typically residing in a file with extension `.nix`.

Every expression has the so-called “symbolic name”, a human-readable name that is printed, when you use `nix-env`. See [sample Nix expression](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-expression-syntax). Nix itself doesn't use this symbolic name anywhere internally, so it doesn't matter if your package is named `aspell-dict-en`, it's just for your, human's, convenience.

What actually matters is the so-called “attribute path”. So your confusion is between symbolic name and attribute path. Every package has an attribute path, which you can use in `environment.systemPackages` configuration option to install system-wide using [declarative package management](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-declarative-package-mgmt).

To find out your package's attribute path, add another flag [`-P`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#idm46912466717184) to your query:

```
$ nix-env -qaP 'aspell.*en'
nixos.aspellDicts.en  aspell-dict-en-7.1-0
```

You should be comfortable using `nix-env` on a daily basis, so practice calling `nix-env` with `--query` and `--install` options. However you can also browse packages and find out their attribute paths online on [Nix packages search](http://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html). Type `aspell`, click on `aspell-dict-en` and you'll see various package's properties, including attribute path as part of the install command:

```
$ nix-env -iA nixos.pkgs.aspellDicts.en
```

Now you can put this attribute path into `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  aspellDicts.en
];
```

Then update the system by running `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `-P` option does not work with `--installed`, as can be seen with `nix-env -q --installed -P | grep terminus` which prints `terminus-font` instead of `terminus_font`. The workaround is to use `nix-env -qaP | grep terminus-font`, but it means that you can't easily dump the output of `nix-env -q --installed` into the `configuration.nix`.

Answer (score 5):

You can search for packages using the following website:

- https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.11&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=openshift

---

In case you are using NixOS for Data Science:

**Python** modules:

```
nix-env -qaP .\*pylint.\*
```

or

```
py_pkgs="nix_packages_py35.txt"
nix-env -qaP | grep -i python36 > ${py_pkgs}
grep pandas ${py_pkgs}
```

OR if your are searching especially for **R** packages/libraries

```
nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A rPackages .\*tidyverse.\*
```

alternatively you get e.g. npm packages with:

```
nix-env -qaPA 'nixos.nodePackages'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nix-env -v -qaP '*' | grep "nvim"
```

I would save the result of `nix-env -v -qaP '*'` to a file (as it usually takes a while to return).

---

Bear in mind, nix-env seems to ignore things under `haskellPackages` (and possibly others).  You can search for packages in subcategories such as haskellPackages via
`nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaPA haskellPackages`

---

nix-env search is currently quite frustrating as it'll take 5+ seconds and then come back with a `error: regex error`...

Answer (score 0):

**Additional** to Mirzhans options: 
you could check `/nix/store` like `grep -irw "programm-name" /nix/store`. But this could be a bit confusing. Also in your home directory you could check the directory `.local/share` for installed programms/apps.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
nix-search () {
    local cache_file=~/.cache/nix/nix-env-qaP

    if [[ "$1" =~ ^--?c(ache)?$ ]]; then
        mkdir -p $(dirname $cache_file)
        echo -n "Caching packages.."
        nix-env -qaP '*' >$cache_file
        echo " "
    else
        grep -iE "$1" $cache_file
    fi
}
```

```bash
$ nix-search --cache
Caching packages.. 

$ nix-search nodejs
nixpkgs.haxePackages.hxnodejs_4
nixpkgs.haxePackages.hxnodejs_6
nixpkgs.elmPackages.nodejs
nixpkgs.nodejs-16_x
nixpkgs.nodejs
nixpkgs.nodejs-18_x
nixpkgs.nodejs-slim-14_x
nixpkgs.nodejs-slim
nixpkgs.nodejs-slim-18_x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the excutable related to the package you could also use nix-locate (https://github.com/bennofs/nix-index).

```
nix-locate bin/hello      
haskellPackages.hscharm.out                     765,944 x /nix/store/m64bng6pyhq3dy1j0v6r5q7vymnbfrzx-hscharm-0.0.2/bin/hellocharm
haskellPackages.hello.out                       773,048 x /nix/store/gzkp9400ah5wzycfijcnw717b8v6i8gm-hello-1.0.0.2/bin/hello
python-cosmopolitan.out                       2,767,939 x /nix/store/cnz516l462r73k19pqf7kykdsxsj4zw5-python-cosmopolitan-3.6.14/bin/hello.com
mbedtls.out                                      48,720 x /nix/store/p9yww15m79lmdg678ipaqrvwi9wvj01r-mbedtls-2.28.0/bin/hello
(lutris-free.out)                                     0 s /nix/store/xyhi94jj4jbbmbl5wy83d91k4pnrw51g-lutris-fhs/usr/bin/hello
(lutris-free.out)                                     0 s /nix/store/av0syxwqf3a4mviiahiq4rv033dbj1gc-lutris-usr-target/bin/hello
hpx.out                                         234,312 x /nix/store/fb980g5ddz16k0bfc8qd0jcf2x7bsw2a-hpx-1.7.1/bin/hello_world_1
hpx.out                                         243,904 x /nix/store/fb980g5ddz16k0bfc8qd0jcf2x7bsw2a-hpx-1.7.1/bin/hello_world_2
hpx.out                                         270,464 x /nix/store/fb980g5ddz16k0bfc8qd0jcf2x7bsw2a-hpx-1.7.1/bin/hello_world_distributed
hello.out                                        55,656 x /nix/store/9ywyxky6cv809jh143f8yxg5kc4bk2yq-hello-2.12/bin/hello
hello-wayland.out                                84,280 x /nix/store/djp0pk61bx3ynxh9w65pnv1vq3z2ja07-hello-wayland-unstable-2020-07-27/bin/hello-wayland
fltk14.bin                                      877,328 x /nix/store/nwkr6p4pmrmx7cnkhya823mhv7x8fski-fltk-1.4.x-2021-12-21-bin/bin/hello
fltk14.bin                                       21,000 x /nix/store/nwkr6p4pmrmx7cnkhya823mhv7x8fski-fltk-1.4.x-2021-12-21-bin/bin/hello-shared
fltk.bin                                        604,656 x /nix/store/v3ijc814y1bmhfr2ca7da95m58jk2a37-fltk-1.3.8-bin/bin/hello
```